# Dictionary int, myclass

Tags: list, c#-4.0, dictionary

```
That's my class

public class PersonelAtama
{
   public int PersonelID { get; set; }
   public int YonetimTalepID { get; set; }
   public bool durum { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do`Dictionary<int,list<myclass>>`

```
 Dictionary<int, List<PersonelAtama>> 
 PersonelAtamaListesi = new Dictionary<int, List<PersonelAtama>>();
```

How to insert into the list

```
PersonelAtamaListesi.Add
```

How assignments are made

```
PersonelAtamaListesi[0][1]  


PersonelAtamaListesi.Add(0,new PersonelAtama()
    {
        PersonelID = personelID,
        YonetimTalepID = yonetimTalepID,
        durum = false
    });
```

assignment into the list and how to use again

I want to add to the list and component values to achieve. I want to sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `List` as `TValue` so:

```
PersonelAtamaListesi.Add(0, new List<PersonelAtama>()
                            {
                                new PersonelAtama()
                                {
                                    PersonelID = 1,
                                    YonetimTalepID = 2,
                                    durum = false
                                },
                                new PersonelAtama()
                                {
                                    PersonelID = 11,
                                    YonetimTalepID = 222,
                                    durum = true
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Aynı anahtara sahip öğe zaten eklenmiş.  PersonelAtamaListesi.Add(0, new List<WLB.PersonelAtama>()
                            {
                                new WLB.PersonelAtama()
                                {
                                    PersonelID = personelID,
                                    YonetimTalepID = yonetimTalepID,
                                    durum = false
                                }
                            });

Comment: What is type of personelID and yonetimTalepID variables?

Comment: int yonetimTalepID = tlp.YonetimTalepID;                                                      for (int i = 0; i < adet; i++)
                {
                    int rndID = randomSayiOlustur(rnd,0, personelSayisi);
                    personelID = PersonelListesi[rndID].ID;

                    PersonelAtamaListesi.Add(0, new List<WLB.PersonelAtama>()

Comment: You are adding 0 as key in dictionary in loop. Dictionary can not have duplicate keys. Try replacing 0 with i

Comment: I want to do : list in (int, list<myclass>)  Sample: 0 > a,b,c  0> a,a,c 1> a,b, c ?  Dictionary<int, List<myclass>>   element add?

Comment: I can not get. Edit yor question or ask another one, because this answer is answer to one question. It is correct. You are getting error not because of this answer is incorrect. Show the full code in new question.